# Como posso reduzir um código python?

Tags: python, automatização

Escrevi um código python para mover os arquivos da pasta "Downloads" para outras pastas automaticamente.
Por exemplo: arquivos .jpg vão para a pasta "Imagens" e arquivos .mp4, para a pasta "Vídeos".

```
import glob, os, shutil

#Pastas destino
pasta_imagens = 'C:/Users/Leonardo/Pictures'
pasta_videos = 'C:/Users/Leonardo/Videos'

#Imagens
imagens = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.jpg"))
imagens = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.jpeg"))
imagens = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.png"))
imagens = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.gif"))
for imagem in imagens:
    if os.path.isfile(imagem):
        shutil.move(imagem, pasta_imagens)

#Videos
videos = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.mp4"))
videos = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.m4v"))
videos = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.mov"))
videos = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.avi"))
videos = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.mpg"))
videos = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.mpeg"))
for video in videos:
    if os.path.isfile(video):
        shutil.move(video, pasta_videos)
```

O código já funciona como eu esperava, porém eu ainda acho que da pra melhorar...

Tentei reduzir as linhas da seguinte forma:

```
imagens = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, "*.jpg", "*.png", "*.jpeg", "*.gif"))
```

Porém não funcionou

Se alguém puder me ajudar a entender o motivo, ficarei muito grato!!

Answer (score -2):

Você pode criar um array com extensões de imagens e depois percorre-lo através de um for e adicionar as extensões no glob.iglob(). Desta forma:

```
imagesExtensions = ["*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif"]
for extension in imagesExtensions:
    imagens = glob.iglob(os.path.join(pasta_downloads, extension))
```

Pode seguir o mesmo raciocínio para os videos e o que mais quiser adicionar, é uma mudança bem básica mas já vai reduzir bem as linhas de códigos

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!!